# Go to top page button after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I created a method that go to the top of the page every time I click on it.
The problem is, I want this button to be shown only if you already scrolled down and not just as default. How can I define it? Here is my code:

show/hide the button - doesn't work:

```
scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >5) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display =  "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

scrolling to top - works:

```
topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: where on your code are you calling the scrollFunction() ??

Answer (score 3):

I use this code, just change the css to suit your needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#scroll').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#scroll').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $('#scroll').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#scroll {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#scroll span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff
}

#scroll:hover {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- BackToTop Button -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="scroll" title="Scroll to Top" style="display: none;">Top<span> </span></a>

  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following example to make a smooth transition:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 20) {


    $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);
  } else {


    $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);
  }

});

$('#return-to-top').click(function() {
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500, 'swing');
});
```

```css
#return-to-top {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#return-to-top i {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="height:700px">
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top" class="btn btn-secondary">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a scroll to top button like the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#autoScrl').hide();
  $("div").scroll(function() {
    $('#autoScrl').show();
  });


});

function goToTop() {
  document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start',
    inline: 'nearest'
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#autoScrl').hide();
  }, 1000);;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Try the scrollbar in the div</p>

  <div id='hhhh' style="border:1px solid black;width:400px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <section id="top">
      <!-- your content -->
    </section>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.' vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever
    since.
    <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  </div>

  <button id='autoScrl' onclick='goToTop()'>Go To Top</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good answer, the only problem I found was it scrolled to the bottom of the main page while scrolling to the top of the snippet. Wouldn't this be an issue for some use-cases?

Answer (score 0):

I see that other answers are based on jQuery, but I suggest you to follow the "Angular way". In Angular you can listen to `scroll` event via `(scroll)="handleScroll()"` and get current offset from top via `Math.abs(this.scroller.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top)` (`getBoundingClientRect().top` returns negative numbers, so we can get absolute values via `Math.abs`). Finally you should get something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper" (scroll)="handleScroll()" #scrollWrapper>
  <div class="scroll" #scroller></div>
</div>
<button *ngIf="showButton" (click)="scrollToTop()">To top</button>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
@ViewChild('scrollWrapper') private scrollWrapper: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('scroller') private scroller: ElementRef;

public showButton: boolean = false;

public handleScroll(): void {
  const offsetTop: number = Math.abs(this.scroller.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top); 
  this.showButton = offsetTop > 5;
}

public scrollToTop(): void {
  this.scrollWrapper.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

And here is a working [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egtnpq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thanks for last comment the effect i want works... but the funcion itself now doesnt work? whats the code in angular for going to top of page?

Comment: for some reason i cant make this work.. here my html:(appComponent):   <div class="wrapper" (scroll)="handleScroll()" #scrollWrapper>
  <div class="scroll" #scroller></div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-main></app-main>
</div>

<button *ngIf="showButton" (click)="scrollToTop()" class="top">To top</button>

Comment: Because you have to adapt it for your code, all that you need is to detect right element for scrolling